# compare lines in a file and if they have similar column X print column Y

Tags: awk

I couldn't find an exact answer to my problem, so I am asking here. I have a very big file, the lines are like the one below:

```
1   GLY     BB    1   
2   GLY     BB    2   
3   SER     BB    3   
3   SER    SC1    4   
4   PHE     BB    5   
4   PHE    SC1    6   
4   PHE    SC2    7  
4   PHE    SC3    8   
5   GLU     BB    9   
5   GLU    SC1   10
```

I want to print column 4 if the numbers in column 1 are equal.

I searched and tried a code like

```
 awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next} $4 in a;
 END{for (i in a) print $4}' file.txt
```

but I couldn't get what I wanted.

My desired output is a file like below:

```
1
2
3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10
```

I am very new to bash, so any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't really have anything with Bash to do.

Comment: is the input guaranteed to be sorted by the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
awk '$1 != prev { if(lines) print lines; lines=""; prev=$1 }
  { lines = lines (lines ? "," : "") $4 }
  END { if(lines) print lines }' file
```

In very brief, we collect the results from `$4` in `lines`, and print it out when `$1` changes. `prev` keeps track of the previous value of `$1`.

Comment: Is there also any way that I can add a counting variable to the code?

I tried:

`for ((i=1;i<475;i++))
do
    awk -v var="$i" '$1 != prev { if(lines) print "[resi_$var]" "\n" lines "\n"; lines="" ; prev=$1 }
        { lines = lines (lines ? " " : "") $4 }' file
done`

But it doesn't read the variable.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what it is that you are attempting to count; and code which doesn't do what you hoped it would doesn't really explain what you are trying to accomplish. The `nl` command can be used to number the output lines; perhaps that can get you started in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, it's a little bit complex. It's related to a biological system, and I need to sort the molecules to make an input file for simulation software. Since the system is too big, it is not possible to do it manually, so I'm trying to write a code for it. I will try `n1` to see if it can title the outputs for me.

Comment: That`s en ell as in Number Lines https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html